# Firebase Web sign in, check for custom value

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

i have a sign in function for my website:

```
function signIn(){

        var email = document.getElementById("txtEmail");
    var password = document.getElementById("txtPassword");


        const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value);
        promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));
        promise.then(() => {
            window.location.replace("main.html");
        });
    }
```

Now when somebody creates an account i'm setting a custom value which is a boolean:

```
isArtist = false;
```

Now what I want is while trying to signup, check if `isArtist` is false or not. How to do this?

EDIT:

my signup function:

```
  function signUp(){

    var userArtistName = document.getElementById("userArtistName").value;
    var userEmail = document.getElementById("userEmail").value;
    var userPassword = document.getElementById("userPassword").value;

        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPassword).then((success) => {
            var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
            var uid;
            if (user != null) {
                uid = user.uid;
            }
            var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
            var userData = {
                userArtistName: userArtistName,
                userEmail: userEmail,
                userIsArtist: true,
                userId: uid,
            }
            firebaseRef.child('users/' + uid).set(userData);
            console.log('User successfully created!');
           // code for replace user
        }).catch((error) => {
            // Handle Errors here.
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
        });
    }
```

And this is my firebase structure:

[image]

Comment: "setting a custom value which is a boolean" -> Where do you set this value? in Firestore? If yes, in which collection?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec thanks for taking your time, I edited my code and provided the structure. Im quite new to javascript, If you have any improvements, feel free to show them to me with code. Appreciate it!

Comment: Your code should work. Which exact problem do  you encounter?

Comment: I want to allow users to login only if userIsArtist = true. This is still missing in my login function and I dont know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to allow users to login only if `userIsArtist = true`.

You cannot prevent a user to login based on a specific value, but you can prevent him to fetch your database. For that you need to write a [Security Rule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) that allows/denies access based on this data.

Something along the following lines:

```
".read": "auth.uid != null && root.child('users/' + auth.uid + '/userIsArtist').val() === true"
```

In parallel, in your front-end, after login, you can logout the user and redirect the user to the login page in case he/she is not allowed.

Something like the following, where after signing in we fetch the Realtime Database based on the user uid:

```
auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value)
.then(userCredential => {
   const userId = userCredential.user.uid;

   return firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).once('value')
})
.then(snapshot => {
  var userIsArtist = snapshot.val().userIsArtist;
  if (!userIsArtist) {
     //Redirect to login or other action or message
  }
});
```

---

However, in this specific case (Role based access right), the recommended approach is to use Custom Claims. See the following documentation items:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security#section-custom

Note that you can [access the Custom Claim from your front-end](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#access_custom_claims_on_the_client) and, similarly to the solution above, you can redirect the user which does not have the `userIsArtist` Custom Claim.

Also note that using the Custom Claim in a Security Rule is different than the Realtime Database example above. See the doc (link in the second bullet point above).

Finally, note that one advantage of using a Custom Claim over the above solution, is that you can use it in the Security Rules of other Firebase services, e.g. Cloud storage.

Comment: Oh there is one litte thing: I want to do something inside if(!userIsArtist) .. that doesnt work. Im not sure why not, if i do console printing if condition is true, nothing is getting printed.

Comment: What do you see if you do: `var userIsArtist = snapshot.val().userIsArtist; console.log(userIsArtist);`? Note that `if (!userIsArtist)` checks is the user is NOT an artist.

Comment: if I do `console.log(UserIsArtist);` there is no console entry about it. I'm only getting the following error: `Uncaught Error: permission_denied at /users/7hYLzbhg6BeC0jbLb6D77CllKgI3: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.` I'm using a catch function now to avoid showing this error in the console, since it tells the UID. Your code is working perfectly, the only thing is inside the `if (!userIsArtist) {}` I can't do any actions

Comment: You said one of the benefits of custom claims are, that you can use them in other fb services. Now for my approach I have an app and a website, where users can register/login. Both of them can login in the app, but only one of them can login into website. As you showed me how to provide users reading data without the isArtist flag, do you think it is okay to start the whole project without using custom claims? I want to "make it better" in a later step after launching. What do you think? And again appreciate it that you're taking your time for teaching me things. Thanks alot!